# Partial search of gmail TO field using IMAP in node not working

Tags: node.js, email, search, imap, gmail-imap

According to [IMAP RFC 3501 6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4):

> In all search keys that use strings, a message matches the key if the
> string is a substring of the field.  The matching is case-insensitive.

However when using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap), gmail does not seem to be respecting this for searches against the TO field. I haven't tried another programming language, but given how the node module is sending commands my suspicion is that gmail itself is not respecting the partial match with the TO field.

**Simplified example of what is going on:**

```
var Imap = require('imap');

var imap = new Imap(
  user: 'myGmailUser',
  password: 'myGmailPassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 994,
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
);

imap.once('ready', function() {
  imap.openBox('[Gmail]/All Mail', function(err, box) {
  
    imap.search(['TO','myGmail'], function(err, searchResult) {
      // no results
    });

    imap.search(['TO','myGmailUser@gmail.com'], function(err, searchResult) {
      // I get my messages as results
    });
  }
});

imap.connect();
```

Viewing the raw message, I can clearly see in the headers `To: myGmailUser@gmail.com`. Confused as to why the full match works but partial match does not.

Also, within gmail itself, if I search for `to:myGmailUser` it returns messages, but not if I search for `to:myGmail`. Although I imagine it would be using a different protocol than IMAP.

Comment: The standard may say one thing, but not every system conforms perfectly to the standard.  I believe GMail can only search whole tokens.

Comment: You can verify whether this is a server (Gmail) issue by connecting directly via IMAP and issuing the commands. My IMAPTalk client is one way you can do this on Windows: http://gigi.nullneuron.net/comp/imaptalk.php